# Get photo from android server to iOS

Tags: swift, sockets, client, nsdata

I want to send image file from android server to iOS client. I'm using swift language and socket programming(ip-port). There is connection. I send/get string data but i can't get image file. How can i get image file on swift side?

[i want to make like this app](http://android-er.blogspot.com.tr/2015/01/transfer-image-between-android-devices.html)

```
        if aStream == self.inputStream{
            var buffer: UInt8 = 0
            var len: Int!


            while (inputStream?.hasBytesAvailable != nil){
                len = inputStream?.read(&buffer, maxLength: 2048)

                if len > 0{

                    var output = NSData(bytes: &buffer, length: len)

                    if output != nil{

                        var img = UIImage(data: output) //Error !!!

                    }
                } 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you add your actual code?

Comment: i edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InputStream` cannot take all data at once; so you need to append the bytes  throughout iteration with an NSMutableData object until `hasBytesAvailable` property is false. Which means you have no bytes left, you got all the image data you need. The code below is Swift 3.0 by the way.

```
var data = NSMutableData()

fileprivate func handleIncomingMessage(_ stream:Stream) {
    if stream === inputStream {
        let bufferSize = 1024
        var buffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: bufferSize))
        while(inputStream.hasBytesAvailable) {
            let bytesRead = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
            if bytesRead >= 0 {
                data.append(&buffer, length: bytesRead)
            }else {
                if bytesRead == -1 {
                    //TODO: Server closed.
                    ITLog.info("Server closed")
                }
            }
        }

        // `NSMutableData` object now has valid image bytes. 
        // Create an UIImage with `data` object.
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        clearSocketData()

    }
}

fileprivate func clearSocketData() {
    data = NSMutableData()
}
```